# Configure Ubuntu 20.04 server on RPI4 to turn off external HDMI backlight after inactivity timeout

Tags: server, 20.04, raspberrypi, backlight

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 server on an RPI4, and want to configure it to disable the external HDMI LCD monitor backlight after a certain amount of inactivity. Not simple screen blanking as shown in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1312192/116968), which blanks the screen as advertised, but leaves the backlight enabled (on my configuration.)

I'm looking for something roughly equivalent to setting the `consoleblank=$TIMEOUT_SECONDS` kernel parameter as I've done in GRUB on Intel systems:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="consoleblank=300"`

...but it appears Ubuntu 20.04 on the PI doesn't use GRUB.  And I can't edit `/boot/config.txt` as is customary on Raspbian systems.

I've found [this Debian Wiki page](https://wiki.debian.org/RaspberryPi4#Ubuntu) which provides some details about the Ubuntu RPI port, but I've not been able to make use of this info (yet.)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the boot configuration files are now located in /boot/firmware/*

See /boot/firmware/README for more info

See [this page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1828300&sid=87ca621779245ff4ab75c8074767860b#p1828300) for clues.

According to [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1506911&sid=f7498e71e5dd1cc4deff0068c486ef79#p1506911) and [this](https://gutow.github.io/Pi-FrakenTablet/Pi_based_artist_drawing_slate.html) the `hdmi_blanking=1` option, placed in /boot/firmware/usercfg.txt, should enable the desired mode once it's implemented...